LG Ultrafine 4K dead? (blank but charging)
After upgrading to macOS 14 Sonoma, my 16" MPB from 2019 doesn't show anything on an LG Ultrafine 4K (24MD4KL-B). I tried it with an M1 Macbook Air, which works fine.
What can I try to fix this?

This happened to me once on an Intel Mac. I fixed it by resetting the SMC.

@LincDavis indeed that fixes it, thank you! (The display works after the system boots, but it probably worked like that before the upgrade too.)

What helped me in the end was turning OFF "Automatic graphic switching" -> display turned on -> then I was able to turn the switching back to ON and go on with my work.
(The problem is back after a restart, so I'm making a note as to what fixes it here, so that I can find it later.)
